# Display 3d secure when attempting a stripe subscription (without payment intents)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I followed the "create subscriptions with elements" tutorials on stripe website, and everything worked perfectly. But now I need to implement 3d secure before a user pays.

My problem, however, is that I don't use the SetupIntent or PaymentIntent. I directly create a subscription and then display a payment form (per the tutorial).

Here is my subscription creation code (backend-PHP):

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(...);
$subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
    'customer' => $customer_id,
    'items' => [[
     'price' => $price_id,
     ]],
     'payment_behavior' => 'default_incomplete',
     'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
]);
```

My front code (JS):

```
stripe.confirmCardPayment(currentClientSecret, {
    payment_method: {
        card: card,
        billing_details: {
        name: "name"
    },
}
```

How can I require 3d-secure?

Reading this page: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure#when-to-use-3d-secure seems to show that I need SetupIntent or PaymentIntent.

Comment: I don't have the same exactly flow as you but from the documentation https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment it seems like you just need to add the `next_action` `redirect_to_url` parameter to the `confirmCardPayment` function. Please see this specific section: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-next_action

Comment: Regarding redirect_to_url, I am not very sure that would work. Because my payment is done per a modal, and so I don't have a URL to redirect to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the Payment Intent (or Setup Intent of there's a trial) created as part of the Subscription creation as part of the process in order to do 3D Secure.  It's all described here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really help me. I know how to get the payment intent when creating a subscription, but I have no idea how to use that to prompt for 3d-secure.

Comment: It's described in the doc I linked: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements#complete-payment